# reading a long name list into mysql and query names

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a tab delimited file with 3000 first and last names

```
bob   schmuckatelli
jane  doe
```

then I also have database with 3 million records

```
id  Fname  Lname   addr          something  
214 jack   frost   444 snow rd   data   data
```

I am pretty sure the best way is to use a tmp db to do it but my mysql is a little rusty.
How do I find the names in the database? I want to locate them and not insert them.

Comment: So, uh, where's the question?

Comment: @Shahar Syntax question. How to set it up. Doing it with one name I think I could do, the second name is messing with me without using php. I am sure it is a lot easier within MySQL since it's a one shot deal.

Comment: Just, read file and insert values to DB.

Comment: You could probably make use of MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: @Shahar http://paste.ee/p/mJMWW

Comment: @brad You're supposed to do something with the id or whatever you need.

Comment: @Shahar id is an empty set.   http://paste.ee/p/Zs2Ri

Comment: I noticed in your paste.ee code that you're using `mysql:hostname=localhost` I'm surprised you haven't mentioned that you didn't get an error. The syntax is `mysql:host=localhost` (host, not hostname) @brad

Comment: @Fred -ii-  I use hostname in another script and it works fine. Same results with host

Comment: Most bizarre. That type of naming convention doesn't work on my server. Oh well, hey... as long as it works for you ;-) @brad

Comment: @Fred -ii-  But it's not working on this script   :(

Comment: code update, I have it bare bones now  http://paste.ee/p/q7QL8

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is open the file and then check each entry in your database. Something along the line of:

```
$file = fopen('names.txt','r'); //change to whatever name it is
$firstname = ''; $lastname = ''; $index = -1; $id = -1;
$tab = '   '; //change this to the delimiter, of course
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    $index = strrpos($line, $tab);
    $firstname = substr($line, 0, $index);
    $lastname = substr($line, $index + strlen($tab));
    $id = $sql->query("SELECT id FROM db_name WHERE Fname='" . $firstname . "' AND Lname='" . $lastname . "'");//query the firstname/lastname. Change db_name to whatever and I'm assuming you don't need to sanitize.
    //do something with the id?
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: @brad Oh then do the same exact thing except make the sql statement `SELECT` and add `WHERE Fname=` the first name and same for last name.

Comment: @brad Okay what's your error? Oh and you might need to use a different method to query since you're using `PDO` not `mysqli`.

Comment: Yes, PDO. I don't even have the mysqli modules loaded.  http://bpaste.net/show/g3Vr6USsDvIcFC83NgSU/

Comment: @brad I don't see anything on that paste. Do you have any errors?

Comment: code and error update   http://bpaste.net/show/200663/
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/votebd/query2.php on line 15
array(0) { }